# Coc: Change setting from key or script

Tags: vim, neovim, coc.nvim

Is there a way to change a Coc settings from script? Extension options are normally stored in the coc-settings.json file. If you want to toggle a specific setting it is slow to open the file, edit and save. Preferable I would like to be able to map a key to an extension setting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `coc#config`
https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/101175f47c15ff11eb599c617ef895f578f758b8/doc/coc.txt

or `g:coc_user_config` .
https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/101175f47c15ff11eb599c617ef895f578f758b8/doc/coc.txt#L890

Comment: Answers with links benefit from explanations

Answer (score 1):

You can change the configurations by `coc#config`, for example:

```
call coc#config('signature', {'preferShownAbove': v:false})
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to post what worked for you.